# Prove that the only $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$-invariant subspace are $0$ and $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ consist of all complex matrices whose trace is zero. If a linear subspace of $W$ satisfies:
>   $$
> \forall P\in GL_2(\mathbb{C}),\;\forall A\in W,\;P^{-1}AP\in W,
> $$
>   we call it an $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$-invariant subspace. Prove that the only $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$-invariant subspace are $0$ and $V$.

I think we can assume $W\ne0$, and pich a nonzero element $A$ of $W$, then to produce any element in $V$. But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: You do have to consider the case of $W = 0$. Part of what you need to prove is that in this case $W$ is invariant, as well as in the case $W = V$. Of course, both of those cases are trivial, but you still have to prove them. For the other direction, when $W \ne 0$ and $W \ne V$, then there exist $A \in W, A \ne 0$ and $B \in V, B \notin W$. Can you find a $P \in GL_2(\Bbb C)$ such that $B = P^{-1}AP$?